# Custom Paragraph Number For Questions List

Tags: android, layout, paragraph

I am trying to do a question and answer application. I have a problem on the screen that appears below. I'm trying to find a right way about how to add the question number. I researched paragraph style on android. but I couldn't find anything. while researching I found something like this in swift language. I looked for a method similar to that done here.

```
  var attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key: Any]()
  let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
  paragraphStyle.headIndent = 15
  attributes[.paragraphStyle] = paragraphStyle
```

I planned to solve with linear layouts, but I was not successful. Can you guide me on what to do

[image]